# Way to make SharePoint custom quick launch links subject to same visibility/permissions as list links

Tags: security, sharepoint, wss-3.0

When I create a new link in quick launch bar in any site, the link is static and is always visible even when a user may not have privileges to view that document, or the document library it is in.  When any document library has a link in the quick launch (via the document library's "Title, Description, and Navigation" setting), the quick launch link is subject to permissions and will not display in the quick launch if the user does not have permissions to see that document library.

Is there a way to achieve that same functionality to have my static URL to a document be subject to the same 'visible if user has permissions to view that document' action?  Possibly some way to add a link on the SharePoint quick launch for a document much the same way I can add a quick launch link with a document library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [audiences](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101690531033.aspx#3) to achieve that. Audiences allow you to target groups of users with specific content. This feature is only available with Microsoft Office SharePoint 2007, it does not exist on Windows SharePoint Services.

You should stick to audiences if possible, but you could also solve the problem by:

- creating a custom quick launch as a server side control
- creating a JQuery script to check permissions and update quick launch (not recommended)